# urllib2 misbehaving with dynamically loaded content

Tags: python, html, ajax, python-3.x, urllib2

**Some Code**

```
headers = {}
headers['user-agent'] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'
headers['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-gb,en;q=0.5'
#headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate'

request = urllib.request.Request(sURL, headers = headers)
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except error.HTTPError as e:
    print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
    print('Error code: {0}'.format(e.code))
except error.URLError as e:
    print('We failed to reach a server.')
    print('Reason: {0}'.format(e.reason))
else:
    f = open('output/{0}.html'.format(sFileName),'w')
    f.write(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

**A url**

http://groupon.cl/descuentos/santiago-centro

**The situation**

Here's what I did:

1. enable javascript in browser
2. open url above and keep an eye on the console
3. disable javascript
4. repeat step 2 (for those of you who have just tuned in, javascript has now been disabled)
5. use urllib2 to grab the webpage and save it to a file
6. enable javascript
7. open the file with browser and observe console
8. repeat 7 with javascript off

**results**

- In step 2 I saw that a whole lot of the page content was loaded dynamically using ajax. So the HTML that arrived was a sort of skeleton and ajax was used to fill in the gaps. This is fine and not at all surprising
- Since the page should be seo friendly it should work fine without js. in step 4 nothing happens in the console and the skeleton page loads pre-populated rendering the ajax unnecessary. This is also completely not confusing
- in step 7 the ajax calls are made but fail. this is also ok since the urls they are using are not local, the calls are thus broken. The page looks like the skeleton. This is also great and expected.
- in step 8: no ajax calls are made and the skeleton is just a skeleton. I would have thought that this should behave very much like in step 4

**question**

What I want to do is use urllib2 to grab the html from step 4 but I cant figure out how.
What am I missing and how could I pull this off?

**To paraphrase**

If I was writing a spider I would want to be able to grab plain ol' HTML (as in that which resulted in step 4). I dont want to execute ajax stuff or any javascript at all. I don't want to populate anything dynamically. I just want HTML.

The seo friendly site wants me to get what I want because that's what seo is all about.

How would one go about getting plain HTML content given the situation I outlined?

To do it manually I would turn off js, navigate to the page, view source, ctrl-a, ctrl-c, ctrl-v(somewhere useful).

To get a script to do it for me I would...?

**stuff I've tried**

I used wireshark to look at packet headers and the GETs sent off from my pc in steps 2 and 4 have the same headers. Reading about SEO stuff makes me think that this is pretty normal otherwise techniques such as hijax wouldn't be used.

Here are the headers my browser sends:

```
Host: groupon.cl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here are the headers my script sends:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: groupon.cl
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Connection: close
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
```

The differences are:

- my script has Connection = close instead of keep-alive. I can't see how this would cause a problem
- my script has Accept-encoding = identity. This might be the cause of the problem. I can't really see why the host would use this field to determine the user-agent though. If I change encoding to match the browser request headers then I have trouble decoding it. I'm working on this now...

watch this space, I'll update the question as new info comes up

Comment: AJAX requests are limited by a [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); when you save your urllib2 result to a file then load that into a browser, you've changed the origin and AJAX calls back to the original server fail. Also, there is no guarantee that the server will serve the same content to urllib2 as it would to your browser (different headers are sent by both). This is **not** a python problem.

Comment: You need to verify that **step 5** has the same headers; the browser does not advertise the fact that JS is disabled in it's headers. Last but not least, how do you exect AJAX calls to `file://` urls to work?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have updated my question with header stuff. Thanks for the note on same-origin policy (+1) it is interesting although not really useful right now since I want to avoid ajax

Comment: And you are absolutely certain that what `urllib2` downloads is the same data that the browser receives?

Comment: I am absolutely sure it is not the same data. I want the same data but I'm not getting it. I want it that if I turn js off and navigate to that page then the html that shows up is the same as what my script is getting. I added a section to my question called 'to paraphrase', maybe it will better explain what I'm after